# How to change scope in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a old Rails project, which is using `paranoia` on the `Order` model, and it did't add `without_default_scope: true` option, so our `Order` have a default scope: `deleted_at IS NULL`.  And we have `resource :orders` in the routes, so when I try to visit a deleted order id on the `orders#show` action, it will try to find the the order with `deleted_at IS NULL` scope, and then raised a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` , like this

> ```
> Couldn't find Order with 'id'=217 [WHERE `orders`.`deleted_at` IS NULL]
> ```

I try to overwrite Rails  behavior with

```
def show
  @order = Order.with_deleted.find(params[:id])
end
```

But it still raise the same error, because it still using the default scope,notice that the error message end with

> [WHERE `orders`.`deleted_at` IS NULL]

, seems Rails behaved before me. How to I find order before Rails?

**update:**
1. The order with id=217 do exists in the database, because I can find it by `Order.with_deleted.find(217)` on Rails console.

**Question closed**:
Sorry I did't known that there is a before filter in my application controller, which will find resource according controller name, I thought it is Rails's default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **unscoped**

```
def show
  @order = Order.unscoped.find(params[:id])
end
```